# Best way to pass data back from class to react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a react app, I want to include a file for websockets (currently a class) but I want to be able to call things in App from it (when the WS provides messages). I'm looking for something like a react callback prop, but I don't think using a component is necessary since this class will not render anything.

Whats the best way to implement this?

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.ws = undefined;
  }

  sendMessage(data) {
    console.log(data)
  }

  connect = () => {
    this.ws = new Websocket();
  };

  render() {
    return <div>
      <button onClick={this.connect}>Connect</button>
      </div>

  }

}

let ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/");
export default class Websocket {

  componentDidMount() {
    ws.addEventListener("message", this.getPosition);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    ws.removeEventListener("message", this.getPosition);
  }

  giveData = ({data}) => {
    //here I want to send the data to sendMessage in App component
  };

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you want a different WebSocket instance for each component in the app (which leads to x number of connections for x components)? or do you want to reuse the same connection for several components?

Comment: I am pretty much only going to use the WS connection in one component (because its a canvas app where most of the logic is in one place)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a class to create multiple instances of a WebSocket connection if you'd like, but

> I'm looking for something like a react callback prop

not sure what you mean by that, but if you want to pass a callback function to be called when the ws instance gets a message you could instead pass the callback to the WebSocket class in the constructor.

Let's say this is your `Websocket` in the file `Websocket.js`

```
export default class Websocket {
  constructor(onMessage) {
    // onMessage is expected to be a callback function
    this.ws = new WebSocket("wss://<url>");
    this.onMessage = onMessage;

    // add the event listener using the custom callback you pass in constructor
    this.ws.addEventListener("message", this.onMessage);
  }

  // when closing the connection to make sure to remove the event listener
  closeConnection = () => {
    // as a cleanup you should call this in your `componentWillUnmount` hook, which will clear the event listeners,
    // in order to prevent memory leaks
    this.ws.removeEventListener("message", this.onMessage);
    this.ws.close();
  };

  // incase you need to reopen the connection
  openConnection = () => {
    // if connection is already open or connecting
    if (
      this.ws.readyState === this.ws.OPEN ||
      this.ws.readyState === this.ws.CONNECTING
    )
      return;
    this.ws.addEventListener("message", this.onMessage);
  };
```

Now, in your `App` component, you can just pass the function you want to be called when message is received like so

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.ws = null;
  }

  sendMessage(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }

  connect = () => {
    // pass sendMessage to be used when receiving socket messages in the constructor
    this.ws = new Websocket(this.sendMessage); 
  };

  // cleanup to ensure eventListeners are cleared
  componentWillUnmount = () => {
    this.ws.closeConnection();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.connect}>Connect</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```